# How do I write a regular expression to replace % by function?

Tags: python, regex

Here are some sample inputs:

```
B%2==1
N%2!=1
```

and I want their corresponding outputs to be:

```
M(B,2)==1
M(N,2)!=1
```

It look very simple but I am not able to write a regular expression for that? Please give me few suggestions

Comment: What does your regex look like so far?

Comment: capture groups with (\w+)%(\w+), replace with M($1,$2), example https://regex101.com/r/eB0cM5/1

Comment: `re.sub(r'^(\w+)%(\d+)(.*)$', r'M(\1, \2)\3, line)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
data= """
B%2==1
N%2!=1
"""

rx = r"([A-Z]+)%(\d+)"

result = re.sub(rx, r"M(\1,\2)", data, 0, re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
```

It will print:

```
M(B,2)==1
M(N,2)!=1
```

Comment: Hi if input is of the form B%2==1&&N%2!=1 What change I have to make

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: My desired output M(B,2)==1&&M(N,2)!=1

Comment: Not sure what's reason of error. but regarding regex, see https://regex101.com/r/zA1eM1/2